# Correctly forward to specializations for dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-specialization

I learned that you can specialize for dynamically allocated arrays with `T[]` :

```
template<typename T>
class C {}; 

template<typename T>
class C<T[]> {};
```

Now while trying to use such machinery, I seem to have trouble composing this feature (using it in an inner layer, eg inside a function template) :

```
#include <iostream>

template<class _Ty>
struct OP
{   
    void operator()(_Ty *_Ptr) const noexcept
    {   
        std::cout << "single pointer\n"; 
        delete _Ptr;
    }
};

template<class _Ty>
struct OP<_Ty[]>
{
    void operator()(_Ty *_Ptr) const noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "dynamically allocated array\n"; 
        delete[] _Ptr;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void f1(T *arg)
{
   OP<T>()(arg); 
}


int main()
{
     f1(new int(3));  
     f1(new int[(3)]);  
}
```

The [above](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96478cded770df45) prints

> single pointer
>
> single pointer

when it's clear that the second call is done with an array. How can I fix this, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `f1` takes a pointer. Array-to-pointer decay occurs and the resulting instantiation for the function is `f1(int*)` for both calls where `T = int`. Therefore the `OP<int>` specialization is selected.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I need to dispatch inside a function. Can I alter the function signature someway to make this work?

Comment: Oops. In my last comment array-to-pointer decay *didn't* occur - the `new` operator always returns a pointer to the allocated memory. Anyway, the way to fix this would be to pass the type explicitly as a template argument and have your call operators take the decayed versions of the types (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ad65025dacd8cd). Also, don't start identifiers with an underscore.

Comment: Both `new int(3)` and `new int[3]` are `int*`s — there is no way to tell them apart. Where did you learn that you can "specialize for dynamically allocated arrays"?

Comment: @molbdnilo  Check [default_delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) . I'd appreciate any thoughts on why this would be a misconception

Comment: @NorahAttkins `std::default_delete` is normally used in a context where its template argument isn't deduced but explicitly provided.

Comment: @0x499602D2 hence your previous comment. So that's the only way :( (on the other topic, I was copy pasting from an STL implementation, and that's how I ended up with those underscores)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your calls are of the same type. We can verify this with a simple program:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        decltype(new int(3)),
        decltype(new int[(3)])
    >{}, "wat");
}
```

That is noted in the standard in [expr.new]:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the noptr-new-declarator syntax is used or the new-type-id or
>   type-id denotes an array type), the new-expression yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array.
>   [ Note: both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]`
>   —end note ] The attribute-specifier-seq in a noptr-new-declarator appertains to the associated array type.

So there is no way to distinguish a pointer to a single element from a pointer to an array *by its type*. You could pass in some additional tag though, like:

```
struct array_tag { };
struct single_tag { };

f1(new int(3), single_tag{});
f1(new int[3], array_tag{});
```

Or just explicitly specify the types (this would require changing a couple other signatures - `f1` would have to take a `T`, not a `T*`, etc):

```
f1(new int(3));
f1<int*>(new int(3));

f1<int[]>(new int[3]);
```